# Migrating Apache Camel 2.x.x to 3.x.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

In our current project we using Java 8, Spring boot 1.5.4.RELEASE with Apache Camel 2.17.1
Team is planning to upgrade camel to 3.4.X because it has the support for java 8.
I saw the camel documentation which states that java 8 support will be discarded from 3.4.X version onward but struggle to find out compatible version of spring boot version required to use with camel 3.4.X
Do i need to upgrade the spring boot version? and if yes which version would be it or where i can find out.

Comment: The [start.spring.io](https://github.com/spring-io/start.spring.io/blob/master/start-site/src/main/resources/application.yml#:~:text=name:%20Apache%20Camel) website recommends Apache Camel versions compatible with Spring Boot versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment suggests, you may follow releases, but the simplest variant is checking Camel starters dependencies. For instance, [camel-core-starter:3.4.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.springboot/camel-core-starter/3.4.4).

Also, note that you will need to read [Camel migration guide 2.X to 3.X](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html) carefully as there tons of changes, starting from library renames to an actual change of behaviors.